# How to implement i18n localization in EJS and gulp only?

Tags: javascript, gulp, internationalization, ejs

I have built a static web page through [EJS](https://ejs.co/) templating. All EJS files are converted to HTML files through the script that I have written in `gulpfile.js` when I run `yarn start`. And it is served through `.dist` folder. I want to implement i18n localization in it. I have all translations like `en.json`, `fr.json`, etc. inside `locales` folder.

Is it possible to implement those translations in EJS?

I have used only the EJS for templating. I have used neither expressJS nor nodeJS. There are no routes either. All the tutorials on the web are based on nodeJS or expressJS.

Comment: I have used only the EJS for templating. I have used neither expressJS nor nodeJS. There are no routes too. All the tutorials are based on nodeJS or expressJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found [gulp-i18n-localize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-i18n-localize) package to solve the problem.